# PyQT app is returning None

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using pyQT 4.11 and I have a serious problem.
I have the following code in a module, called OpenFileDialog called from another window:

```
    try:
        app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        print "OFD app-try"
    except:
        app=QtGui.QApplication.activeModalWidget()
        print"OFD app-try failed. App is:"
        print app
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the MainWindow class, I run the following lines 

`self.setModal(True)
dg=OpenFileDialog.Ui_Form(item,self)`

When I run the same check at the beginning of the MainWindow class, 
`<PySide.QtGui.QApplication object at 0x03EB1490>`
 is printed, so I do have a QApplication going.
I created the constructor to require an item and the caller.
The only problem is that it prints "OFD app-try failed. App is:
None" so that my GUI is screwed up so that the layout is "". The error looks like this:

```
sys.exit(app.exec_())  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exec_'
```

The except block is meant to be triggered, since there is already a QApplication instance running, and that is reflected when `raise`d. This window is being called from a Main Window.
What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Which version of PyQt are you using?

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], currently your code is not, since it is not complete.

Comment: It would also be useful to know what the exception being raised is (add `raise` at the end of the except block)